# jQuery $.each first element is always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm having an issue that i can't fix, i don't know why the first iteration of the $.each() is always printing a "undefined", for example:

```
undefined
Element one
Element two
...
```

Code

```
var preview = function(){
      var values = {};
      var el ;

      $.each($('form').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        values[field.name] = field.value;
      });

      $.each(values,function(key,obj){
        if(obj){
            el += key+" : "+obj;
        }
      });

      console.log(el);
  };
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you add a sample of the data

Comment: Initialize var el = ""; In your case, it's value is undefined

Comment: @DhavalMarthak In this case that is not the reason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just modify `var el ;` to `var el = ""`;

You haven't initialized `el` and that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with changing the line `var values = {};` to `var values = [];`